# JSON Parsing using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, json

I'd like to know if I can parse & filter JSON text data based on a regular expression; say for example I have the following

```
{"key":"some:xx:yy", "value": 72311}
{"key":"some:xx:zz", "value": 72311}
{"key":"some:xx:qq", "value": 72311}
```

I want to select all tuples that have for the key field the same "some:xx:" part, how can I archive this using JSON in an 'elegant' way?

Comment: This is invalid JSON, do you perhaps have an _array_ of objects here? (That is `[...objects here...]` )

Comment: Why oh why would you use a RegEx in JavaScript to parse JSON?

Comment: @Madbreaks he isn't parsing json - he is likely mixing JS object and array literals with the JSON data exchange format and actually wants to filter an array based on regex. Something like `filtered = myList.filter(function(obj){ return obj.key.indexOf("some:xx") === 0;});`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum yea, sorry it's an array of JSON data objects; at least it looks like it and that's what Apache AVRO spits out. Will indexOf give the expected results?

Comment: @jtimz please update your question with the _actual_ output of your code.

Comment: @jtimz It's an array of javascript objects, not json. json has nothing  to do with it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum actually this is the actual output avro produces, if you take an avro serialized pile of objects and use avro tools to translate it to json like so "java -jar avro-tools-version.jar tojson out.avro", produces output similar to the one I provided you above.

Answer (score 0):

The example you gave contains three different objects. So you can use javascript to look for text in a property.

```
obj1 = {"key":"some:xx:yy", "value": 72311};

if (obj1.key.indexOf("xx") !== -1) {  // obj1.key contains "xx"
    //do something
}
```

If you have an array with those values, then you can simply loop through the array and look for "xx" just like above for each element of array. And when found, you can assign that element to another array. So at the end of the loop, "another array" will contain all elements that contain "xx".

If you don't insist on using RegEx, i can show you an example code for the loop. If you insist on RegEx, let me know and i will help you.. just kidding, let me know and i will delete my answer and silently leave this question :)

Comment: RegEx would be the way I'd perform it using Shell, but that works as well; I can figure out the specifics myself as indexOf (as it was pointed by @Benjamin previously) seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give you a straight answer to the question you asked, but hopefully the complexity and the raft of caveats will convince you that `JSON.parse` is a better alternative.

---

You can write a regular expression to match a single such tuple, but you can't write a regular expression to match all such tuples.

To explain why, consider the regular expression that matches one:

```
var stringBody = '(?:[^"\\\\]|\\\\.)*';
var string = '"' + stringBody + '"';
var space = '[ \t\r\n\f]*';
var colon = space + ':' + space;
var comma = space + ',' + space;

var uglyRegex = '^(?:[^"]|' + string + ')*?'
    + '"key"' + colon + '"(some:xx:' + stringBody + ')"' + comma
    + '"value"' + colon + '((?:[^\},"]|' + string + ')*)';
```

This works by finding the minimal number of non-string or full-string tokens that precede a key whose value starts with `some:xx:` and then looks for a value.

It leaves the key in matching group 1 and the value in matching group 2.

Since it has to match starting at the beginning to correctly identify string token boundaries, it cannot be used in a `'g'` flag match.

## Caveats

1. It assumes certain characters in `"key"`'s property value are not `\uABCD` escaped.
2. It assumes characters in the property names `"key"` and `"value"` are not `\uABCD` escaped.
3. It requires the key and value to occur in that order.
4. It cannot tell what other properties occur in the same object.

Each of these problems could be worked around by making the regex much more complex, but with regular expressions, often, the only way to handle a corner case is to make the regex much bigger.

When incremental improvements to code explode the size, the code is unmaintainable.

Comment: I am leaning towards indexOf to find all such tuples... as this looks quite ugly; and you perfectly name it as such!

Comment: Fixed substring matching comes with an even larger set of caveats, so any solution based on it will be very brittle indeed.

Comment: Well @Mike, what would be a good (and elegant, above all) way of accomplishing the requested facility? All things considered.

Comment: @jtimz, You can write a [stringify replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_native_JSON#The_replacer_parameter) to censor all records that don't have a key like the one you want.